# Stream Webcam Feed to Server - webRTC

Tags: python, opencv, webrtc, rtmp, live-streaming

I have setup a raspberry pi to stream an h264 video feed from a camera to a remote host running Red5 Pro. The program is written in python as uses ffmpeg to transmit with camera feed. On the backend, I use openCV `cv::VideoCapture` to read the stream and process it. Im currently using RTMP and finding an ~1 sec delay. Along with RTMP, Red5Pro also supports webRTC which has a lower latency.

Can anyone explain how to send a video from a camera to a remote host using webRTC. All the information I found has been for streaming video to a local browser.